# Fatal error: Call to a function on a non-object in

Tags: php, sql, function

I'm printing out information from a table (tblgroups). And after that I want to print out avatars (from tblusers) from members of a group (tblgroup_member)

When I try to get push the group_id (from the group I'm printing out) to the function Getmembers) it's telling me that I'm calling a function on a non-object ( `$memberinfo = $group->Getmembers($group["group_id"]);`). But I declare `$group = new Group();` ?

It's telling me that the fault is at this line: `$memberinfo = $group->Getmembers($group["group_id"]);`

PHP

```
$group = new Group();
                foreach ($groups as $group) {



                        echo "<p  class='groupname'><a href='group.php?group_id=" . $group['group_id']. "'>" . $group['group_name']  . "</a></p>"; 
                        echo $group['group_id'];

                        $memberinfo = $group->Getmembers($group["group_id"]);
                    /*  
                        foreach ($memberinfo as $member)
                        {
                            echo "<p>" . $member['avatar'] . "</p>";
                        }

                        */
                }
```

FUNCTION GETMEMBERS (if necessary)

```
public function Getmembers($group_id) {
        $db = new Db();

            $select = "SELECT

                            g.group_id,
                            m.user_id,
                            u.avatar

                        FROM ((tblgroups g INNER JOIN tblgroup_member m ON g.group__id = m.group__id) INNER JOIN tblusers u ON u.user_id = m.user_id)
                        WHERE g.group_id = " .  $group_id . " ";



        $result = $db -> conn -> query($select);
        $result_array=array();
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
             $result_array[]=$row;                                                                                          
        }
        return $result_array;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you have

```
$group = new Group();
```

and then a loop

```
foreach ($groups as $group) {
```

inside the loop you are using

```
$memberinfo = $group->Getmembers($group["group_id"]);
```

here `$group->` does not mean the object its the array data from the `foreach`. or in other words its getting over-written and `$group` is no longer an object

**Solution**

change

```
$group = new Group();
```

to

```
$group_obj = new Group();
```

then

```
$memberinfo = $group->Getmembers($group["group_id"]);
```

to

```
$memberinfo = $group_obj->Getmembers($group["group_id"]);
```

Comment: Stupid to overwrite my code... Thanks, It's working right now!